# subscription management does not verify hostname in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

Subscription management does not verify hostname in cnosdb, user can create a subscription with any hostname:

```
db001 ❯ create subscription sub002 on db001 destinations all "nothostNAME";
Query took 0.006 seconds.
```